# .Net Office365.OutlookServices beta version available?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365api, outlook-restapi

Looks like OutlookServices-V2.0 last Updated on Oct 27 2016 and there is no info about beta / next versions
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/

but the Rest Api has beta version available.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests

what is the guidance regarding this, Move to Rest Api or wait for OutlookServices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That NuGet package won't be updated. So the guidance here would be to move to Microsoft Graph API (if possible), and failing that, to invoke the REST API directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the Microsoft Graph .Net sdk going to be supported in future? or is it better to Just use REST API ?

Comment: MS Graph SDK are going to supported going forward.